# jQuery .css() does not work over iterated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the style of particular input tag if its attribute name is equal to select tag value. But i receive an error which is - `elem.css is not a function` any solution is much appreciated.

```
 const calcTyp = $('#calcTyp'); // select tag
 var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
 jQuery.each(elems, function(i, elem){
   calcTyp.change(function () {
      if(calcTyp.val() == $(elems).attr("name")) {
        elem.css('border-color', 'green');
      }
   });
 });
```

Comment: Why even loop? It is just a selector. Why mix jQuery and DOM?

Comment: `$(elems).attr("name")` makes no sense

Answer (score 3):

As [`css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) is a jQuery method, you have to add jQuery reference to `elem`:

```
$(elem).css('border-color', 'green');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to iterate over your elements using `$.each`. You can simply pass a function as the second positional argument:

```
$('input[type="text"]').css('border-color', function() {
  return calcType.val() === $(this).attr('name') ? 'green' : '';
});
```

That is because most jQuery methods can implicitly iterate through the collection of elements that matches the selector.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const calcType = $('#calcType');

calcType.on('input', function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').css('border-color', function() {
    return calcType.val() === $(this).attr('name') ? 'green' : '';
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Calc type: <select id="calcType">
  <option disabled selected>Choose one</option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="text" name="a" />
<input type="text" name="b" />
<input type="text" name="c" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing jquery and DOM is normally not the best. You had two issues in the code that caused an error and caused wrong checks.

```
 var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
 jQuery.each(elems, function(i, elem){
   //if(calcTyp.val() == $(elems).attr("name")) { <-- wrong variable here
   //  elem.css('border-color', 'green');  <-- DOM element treated like jQuery
   //}
   if(calcTyp.val() == $(elem).attr("name")) { 
     $(elem).css('border-color', 'green');
   }
 });
```

There is no need to loop, all you needed to do was make a selector that matched on name.

```
$('input[type="text"][name="' + calcTyp.val() + '"]').css('border-color', 'green');
```